# Skype For Business Online UCWA application server stops working after some time

Tags: skype-for-business, ucwa

the last couple of days I implemented the autodiscovery/auth flow for UCWA against Skype for Business Online and AzureAD. When I'm done and having the URL to the application directory (+ the OAuth2 Credentials) I save those into our internal system. So later on I want to create online meetings with this data. The URL to the applications directory looks like this: `https:\/\/webpoolam42e10.infra.lync.com\/ucwa\/oauth\/v1\/applications\/101331226048\/onlineMeetings\/myOnlineMeetings`

If I do this within the first minutes of retrieving the data it works just fine. But later on it seems, that the application directory is gone. I'm getting this response:

```
body":"{\"code\":\"NotFound\",\"
subcode\":\"ApplicationNotFound\",\"message\":\"An error occurred. Please retry. If the problem persists, contact your support team.\"}
```

Status Code is 404.

Later on I even tend to get 401 errors that mean unauthorized.

I suspect the application server going away and only being temporarily available. I got a refresh token and a valid access token, so this wont be a problem. I've got no clue what is going on there and wasnt able to find help in the docs. So maybe one of you got any advice - I'd be really thankful!

Side-Info:
I'm doing all this in PHP and I only have user-interaction at the initial authentication. I save the refresh token and all other things I need, so that my server-side application can use the authorization in long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reporting here part of my reply to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511143/using-ucwa-api-for-chatbot/42530890#42530890):

Keeping a UCWA App always online:

If you need to achieve that, you need to understand and implement correctly the concepts explained here [me Dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/medashboard), especially at *Reporting activity* section:

- call reportMyActivity every 4 minutes max.
- maintain an active P-GET with the Events Channel
- handle possible timeouts on the Events Channel
- handle possible DELETE events (on the Events Channel) the server can send for the application, for which you'll have to regenerate your app [Application dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/applicationdashboard)

reporting app's activity, and keeping a valid open P-GET with Events Channel are both very important!

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I figured out by just creating a new app every time I need to create a meeting link.

Comment: @Massimo Prota .. Please answer my question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57170656/skype-for-business-receive-im-not-working-with-the-below-steps ..  I am not able to receive im, in skype for business UCWA api. As you have already worked on this, I am not able to receive any IM in UCWA.  Please guide me sir.